# Generated Avro Builder set null doesn't overwrite with default

Tags: java, avro

In my avro schema, I've defined a field like this

```
{
  "name": "myfield",
  "type": "string",
  "default": ""
}
```

When I build my avro object in java I set `myfield` to be `null` (my code is just copying values from one place to another)

```
MyObject myObject = MyObject.newBuilder().setMyfield(null).build();
```

I end up with

```
myObject.getMyfield() == null
```

Is this the expected behaviour? Am I doing something wrong? I've have expected that we'd end up with the default value `""`.

Because `null` isn't a valid value for this field when I try and serialise the object (for sending to kafka)

Do I need to null check this field before calling the setter on the `Builder`

Comment: This looks like a bug in Avro. The setter should throw an exception, if the argument is `null`. This should be independent of the default value in the schema.

Answer (score 1):

I got around this problem by allowing `null`s. Maybe it's better to default to `null` (meaningless) rather than `""` (has some meaning) anyway.

```
{
  "name": "myfield",
  "type": [
    "null",
    "string"
  ],
  "default": null
}
```